# Regex check if string first characters are digits

Tags: java, regex

Trying to use Regex to detect is a String starts with 2 characters followed by an optional space, followed by an optional letter.

This is my attempt: but does not seem to catch my test data

```
!string.matches("\\b\\d{2}\\s?[a-Z]?")
```

Test Data:

```
23: sentence here
```

Comment: `contains` doesn't use regex.

Comment: Ahh, thank you. What would you suggest to find regex in String? (fairly new to Java).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`contains` doesn't use regex. You may want to create Pattern and then for each of your string separate Matcher and check if it can `find` regex you described. So your code can look like

```
private static final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^\\d\\d\\s?[a-Z]?");
public static boolean test(String str){
    return p.matcher(str).find();
}
```

(you can rename this method into something more descriptive)

---

You could try with `yourString.matches(regex)` but this method checks if regex matches entire string, not just part of it, which means that it can be inefficient if your string is long, and you want to check only first few characters.

Answer (score 1):

Use `matches` instead of `contains`:

```
!string.matches("^\\d{2}\\s?[a-Z]?.*")
```

The regular expression works like this:

- `^` searches the beginning of the string
- `\\d{2}\\s?[a-Z]?` was your search pattern
- `.*` allows the rest of the string to be anything

Have a look at the API:

- contains: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29
- matches: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29